# Output Text to Octave Console

Tags: console, line, octave, output

Lets say I have a variable `A=5` and i want to output it, but with some text added in front and after it. Something like this:   `"There are 5 horses."`  (mind that `5` should be changable variable `A`)

If I write: `disp("There are "),disp(A),disp(" horses.")`  I get:

```
There are 
5
 horses.
```

BUT I want everything in one line.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use:

```
A = 5
printf("There are %d horses\n", A)
```

output:

```
There are 5 horses
```

or even

```
disp(["There are ", num2str(A), " horses"])
```

or even

```
disp(strcat("There are ", num2str(A), " horses"))
```

but you will have to add something because octave/matlab don't let the white space at the end of a string, so the output is:

```
ans = There are5 horses
```

Comment: None of your examples is to actually display, they all generate a string which are only printed as side effect of not being assigned anywhere. That's why you get the `ans =` also printed. The only correct answer is to use `printf` (I edited your answer), or to use display around your other examples) (you should edit your answer for those).

Comment: @ThiS How to display a string and matrix using the same disp() call for e.g. disp("Matrix is - ", M); where M is a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

As per [official documentation](https://octave.org/doc/v4.4.1/Terminal-Output.html),

> Note that the output from `disp` always ends with a newline.

so to avoid the newline, you should use an alternative to output data for each string, or first concatenate a single string and then `disp` it.

ThiS [listed options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15267714/2707864).